# SpecFlow vs Cuke4Nuke vs Cucumber+IR

Tags: cucumber, bdd, specflow

Having a look at BDD frameworks and I can't help but wonder which one would suit us better.
I like Cucumber because, they have been there doing BDD for a good while(since early 2008)  and I like Ruby, however, we are a .net shop and although I find Ruby very friendly, other people  don't; and I think that is fair enough (to a point)
Cuke4Nuke, I can see it uses Cucumber under the hood, but it seems to be very early days.
I haven't actually tested SpecFlow but I heard good things about it and I know it uses the same meta language for specification 
I have looked into StoryTeller, could be nice, but I need something that is gonna be there in the next 5-10 years, and I dont know if that will be.

So what do you think is a good suit?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I prefer Cucumber, Cuke4Nuke, and Cuke4Vs.
We don't just do .NET development.
This allows performing BDD with ruby and Java (Cuke4Duke) using similar tools.
I just like the consistency of use across multiple languages for development.  Since Cuke4Nuke is a wire protocal, Cuke4 adapters for almost any language could be developed.

The only issue my team will soon have is Cuke4Vs does not work with VS2010 right now and we will be upgrading soon.  Of course you don't need CukeVs to use Cuke4Vs, it just makes it easier for the developers.

I agree that it is not necessarily better than SpecFlow.  I tried it and it works good.  If you only have .NET development and no Ruby/IronRuby, Java, etc.  It can be a good choice as well.

Answer (score 3):

SpecFlow is better at the moment, it is stable and has better integration with visual studio 2008/2010.

You can also refer to here:
[Cuke4Nuke or SpecFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113936/cuke4nuke-or-specflow)

Comment: "Better" is highly subjective. Cuke4Nuke + Cuke4Vs gives you a similar feature set. There is no Ruby to write for developers.

Comment: I agree better is highly subjective. Let me add to what schrodinger's code said. I like that I can run my SpecFlow tests with any NUnit test runner. I use ReSharper, but the NUnit test runner works, also. Cuke4Nuke I was using a command line. Overcoming that small practicality would help the Cuke4Nuke camp.

Answer (score 2):

SpecFlow has better accepted by .Net community you can read more about at [Richardlawrence's](http://www.richardlawrence.info/2011/10/21/the-future-of-cucumber-on-net/) Blog one of the creator of the Cuke4Nuke.