# What is the standard way to do BDD in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, bdd

What is the standard way to do BDD in VS2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpecFlow or Cuke4Nuke.

Here's a link to the advantages and disadvantages of both projects: [Cuke4Nuke or SpecFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113936/cuke4nuke-or-specflow)

SpecFlow is probably what you're asking for. It's advantages (I lifted this from the aforementioned article):

- A pure .NET solution (so no
  installation of Ruby is necessary and
  Ruby is not involved at runtime)
- There is a basic integration with
  VisualStudio (and there are plans to
  evolve this)
- Scenarios are basically UnitTests and
  can be run with your existing
  infrastructure (NUnit.Runners,
  ReSharper, VisualStudio MSTest
  Integration ...)
- Scenarios and steps are easily
  debuggable out of VisualStudio (just
  set a breakpoint)
- Integration in your continuous build
  should be a breeze, since the
  infrastructure to run unit-tests is
  most certainly there already

Almighty Steve Sanderson has a blog post about using SpecFlow for BDD in Asp.Net MVC: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/03/behavior-driven-development-bdd-with-specflow-and-aspnet-mvc/

Here's the SpecFlow homepage:
http://specflow.org/

Good luck!